# List has invalid arguments

Tags: c#, list, object

I have following classes:

```
public class Selections
{
    public List<Selection> selection { get; set; }
}

public class Selection
{
    public Promotion promotion { get; set; }
    public Products products { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    public List<int> productId { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating List and assigning property values but when I am adding the list I'm getting error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(Selection)' has some
>   invalid arguments

**C# code:**

```
Selections productSelections = new Selections();
List<Selection> listOfProductSelections = new List<Selection>();
Selection dataSelection = new Selection()
{
    promotion = new ProviderModels.Common.Promotion()
    {
        promotionID = Convert.ToInt32(applicablePromotion.PromotionId),
        lineOfBusiness = applicablePromotion.LineOfBusiness
    },
    products = new ProviderModels.Common.Products()
    {
        productId = GetIdsOfSelectedProducts(context, selectedOffer)
    }
};
productSelections.selection.Add(listOfProductSelections);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a list to another list. You want to add the list items.

Instead of

```
productSelections.selection.Add(listOfProductSelections);
```

write

```
productSelections.selection.AddRange(listOfProductSelections);
```

But you have to be sure you have initialized the `selection` property at that point, otherwise you'll run into a `NullReferenceException`.

By the way, check *all* your error messages. You will see a second message telling you which type is excpected and what you were using.

Comment: Ok. but before that I have to add `listOfProductSelections.Add(dataSelection)` also. Right? Also I do run into null reference exception although I initialized `Selection dataSelection = new Selection()`

Comment: In the code above you call `AddRange`on `productSelections.selection`. If that property is not initialized, it will be `null`. So you will run into the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `AddRange` as `listOfProductSelections` is a list.

```
productSelections.selection.AddRange(listOfProductSelections)
```

Answer (score 0):

productSelections.selection is a reference to a List, consquently when you try to add an item to it (last line of your example) the *Add* method expects a parameter of type of *Selection* - you're passing *listOfProductSelections* which is a reference to another list.

Maybe you wanted to add *dataSelection* which is of the required type? If not, you can use *AddRange* as the other respondents have suggested.